# Can I install other OS's on the given MicroSD card for my pi 4?

Tags: pi-4

I recently bought a canakit raspberry pi 4 with all the works -- cables, case, and a 32 GB microSD card. I want to learn how to use other Linux OS's, like: Ubuntu, Kali, etc.

With the given SD card, can I boot those OS's onto it and install them on my pi 4? I'm worried of corrupting my SD card, I'm not very knowledgeable in this stuff (yet).

Comment: It will be easier and more foolproof to have multiple SD cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md)
to install multiple OS and configure the Pi to boot to any of the installed OS. AFAIK this only supports 32bit OS.

32 GB is not large enough, you may be able to squeeze 3 OS on to it.

Frankly it is easier to install to different SD Cards and swap these.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you use the Raspberry Pi Imager App for this. Within the app you can select which OS you want to download on the Pi.